# Are Star-Lord's final words a reference to something else?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, guardians-of-the-galaxy, origin

After watching [*Guardians of the Galaxy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/) and *Peter Quill*'s final words:

> What should we do next? Something good? Something bad? A bit of both?

a friend of mine meant that he thinks to know this quote from somewhere else, but wasn't sure where, some Western maybe. I first thought he might just be messing it up with the title of the movie *The Good, The Bad and The Ugly*. But he said that he also thought that at first, but thinks it to be an actual quote from something else, maybe *Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid* or something similar.

I would thus like to know **if this line from *Star-Lord* is a known quote from some other movie and further if this might even have been a reference to that movie**. But maybe my friend was really on the wrong track or the quote is too general to make any reasonable assessments about its origin.

Comment: I also felt the same and once though to post it but forgot, anyways +1.

Comment: A quick Google search doesn't seem to reveal anything on the first few pages, but that could also be due to the movie's current popularity mucking with the rankings.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson [Not gone yet. ;)] This also might simply *sound* familiar because "bit of both" is a popular trope to describe people\situations (it's said a lot in response to 'business or pleasure'). The closest I can currently find with this phrase on IMDb is *Van Helsing* ("Some say you're a murderer, Mr. Van Helsing. Others say you're a holy man. Which is it?" "It's a bit of both") and *Watchmen* ("It rains on the just and unjust alike. The Comedian was a little bit of both")

Answer (score 2):

In this particular instance, I do not believe the line spoken by Starlord to the Guardians of the Galaxy at the end of the movie was in reference to anything, it seems, more than anything, to be setting itself up for there being a second Guardian's of the Galaxy movie:

> What should we do next? Something good? Something bad? A bit of both?
>   *Roll Credits*

The reason you may find the concept to be familiar is probably down to word arrangement, "The Good, The Bad, and The Ugly" would provide you with familiarity over the "Good" and the "Bad", crossed with "Something old, something new...", both of which are common phrases.

Answer (score -2):

If you actually think about it. "A little bit of both" is a line that Michael Knight uses several times in the Knight Rider series... and since David Hasselhoff is his idol it makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! This answer would be better if you could provide a reference showing that "A little bit of both" is said even once in Knight Rider, let alone several times.